# Different toolbar behavior in different fragments... how?

Tags: android, android-fragments, toolbar

I have an activity (`MyActivity`) with two fragments (`MyFirstFragment` and `MySecondFragment`). I want the screens correspondent to the two fragments to **display the same exact toolbar**: just the 'home' button ('') and the top right corner menu, with only one item (let's call it `Foo`).

The only difference among them should be the behavior when clicking on `Foo`. (Just to make an example, when I'm on `MyFirstFragment` and I press `Foo` I want it to display a Toast, while whem I'm on `MySecondFragment` I want it to open an AlertDialog).

What do you think could be the **best implementation for this**?
Can I define the toolbar inside `MainActivity.java` but then set two different behaviours in each fragment java file? How?

I'll add some code, here's how I'm defining the toolbar inside my `MyActivity.java` for the moment:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // [...]
    Toolbar tb = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_my);
    setSupportActionBar(tb);
    if (getSupportActionBar() != null)
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    tb.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           onBackPressed(); //goes to the previous fragment 
        }
    });
    // [...]
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.foo:
        // do something
        return true;
    default:
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, just define your `Toolbar` inside `MyActivity.java` and then in each fragment constructor set [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setHasOptionsMenu(boolean)) flag to `true`. Then override `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)` with different behavior in each fragment.